# SAS Restructure Data

Tags: sas, transpose

I need help restructuring the data. My Table looks like this

```
 NameHead Department Per_test Per_Delta Per_DB Per_Vul  
 Nancy    Health     55       33.2      33     63  
 Jim      Air        25       22.8      23     11  
 Shu      Water      26       88.3      44     12   
 Dick     Electricity 77      55.9      66     10   
 Elena    General    88       22        67     9  
 Nancy    Internet   66       12        44     79
```

And I want my table to look like this

```
NameHead    Nancy   Jim    Shu      Dick        Elena    Nancy   
Department  Health  Air    Water    Electricity General Internet   
Per_test    55       25     26      77            88    66  
Per_Delta   33.2     22.8   88.3    55.9          22    12   
PerDB       33       23     44      66            67    44   
Per_Vul     63       11     12      10            9     79
```

I tried proc transpose but couldnt get the desired result. Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that your first example has the variable names as the first row. What variable names do want for your result table?  Your example does not show any.

Comment: I just edited the tables...hope it makes it clearer. I want the NameHead to be my first row.

Comment: What names do you want for the variables in your output dataset? Or do you just want a report? If a report what format do you want the report, PDF, RTF, Excel sheet, text file?

Answer (score 0):

PROC TRANSPOSE does exactly what you want.  You must include a `VAR` statement if you want to include the character variables.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want;
  var _all_;
run;
```

Note that you cannot have variables that do not have names.  Here is what the dataset looks like.

```
Obs _NAME_            COL1         COL2         COL3         COL4         COL5         COL6

 1  NameHead      Nancy        Jim          Shu          Dick         Elena        Nancy
 2  Department    Health       Air          Water        Electricity  General      Internet
 3  Percent_test            55           25           26           77           88           66
 4  Percent_Delta         33.2         22.8         88.3         55.9           22           12
 5  Percent_DB              33           23           44           66           67           44
 6  Percent_Vul             63           11           12           10            9           79
```

Comment: Those are not "column names". They are the names of the variables that hold the data.  Variables have to have names. NameHead is not the column header, it is the value of the first column and the first row. You can make a report that doesn't include the variable names if you want.